# Can we install multiple hive servers in the same cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I would like to enable two application instances to share a single HDFS cluster, but each instance of the application requires its own Hive database.

Is there a way to configure multiple independent Hive Servers/Metastores within a cluster so that each application can use the data in the cluster?

Comment: why not create two separate database in the same hive cluster? Any specific reason for this ?

Comment: @ Rishu - I wanted to create two separate Hive instances, One is for Final Tables those meta data i am going to store in AWS RDS, and few static tables which are going to vary for each run,  I want them in Separate meta-store, on each application start and create a new set of static tables on new database with run number for future analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> each instance of the application requires its own Hive database

Then do `CREATE DATABASE my_own_database;` in Hive.

Before any queries in the other app, run `USE my_own_database;` or `SELECT * FROM my_own_database.table`

---

Otherwise, sure, you would have to install and configure a separate Hive metastore Java process pointing at a different database (or even separate server)

in hive-site.xml

```
 <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:<protocol>://<host>:<port>/<databasename></value>
 </property>
```

Then your applications would have to set `hive.metastore.uris` to point at that instance